# AVRDude executable can not be found. Check in the AVR Preferences if the path to AVRDude is correct

Tags: c, eclipse, avr, avrdude

Helo,

I've installed AVR Plugin for Eclipse C/C++ from here http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Plugin_Download .

My problem is, that when I right click on my project and then "Properties -> AVR -> AVRDude -> New...", the following message occurs:

AVRDude executable can not be found.

Check in the AVR Preferences if the path to AVRDude is correct.

Reason:
Cannot run AVRDude executable. Please check the AVR path preferences.

Cannot run AVRDude executable. Please check the AVR path preferences.
Cannot run program "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/ports/cross/avrdude": error=13, Permission denied

Normally, there is an option, where you can set the path (AVR -> Path). See the screenshot, there is no option to do this.

I'm using Mac OS Mojave.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1iMz.jpg

Comment: Did you install AVRDUDE?

Comment: @dunajski: Yes, I installed from Macports. Avrdude is in /usr/local/bin/. But I don't know how to set the correct path. The AVR Plugin for Eclipse looks at /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/ports/cross/avrdude, but there is no avrdude.

Comment: What you got on table in Window->Preferences->AVR->Paths?